# Parse String to Double.NaN

Tags: java, string, nan

i want to let users edit a field with double data. I want to allow `Double.NaN` (to void values). Is there a generic way (a predefined string) that is parsed to `Double.NaN` from the method `Double.valueOf(String)` without checking it in the background?

There is a special char looking like a diamond with a question mark in it (in HTML) that acts like NaN, but - well - the users wont find that on their keys.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass `+NaN` or `-NaN` or `NaN` to `valueOf()` and have it return a NaN. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) gives the full details.

Comment: Ok that works, but not for my special case. I should have mentioned that I use Groovy/Grails to parse it from HTML Form data to the double. It says it is a "Unparseable number" and quits with an IllegalArgumentException. Maybe another method is invoked to convert the property...

Comment: That's not the question you asked though. You asked about `Double.valueOf`. Sounds like you need a new question.

Comment: I thought the conversion process invokes Double.valueOf(String) by itself and is therefore a plain Java related thing, but apparently it is not. Its hard to debug and find what is really called. I'm sorry for that unclear question!

Comment: Opened a new question with hopefully better formulated question at [http://stackoverflow.com/q/10751338/1009459](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10751338/1009459)

Answer (score 3):

`parseDouble("NaN")` will return a `NaN` value:

```
System.out.println(Double.isNaN(Double.parseDouble("NaN"));
```