# Groovy/Grails autoconvert NaN string to double field

Tags: grails, groovy, double, nan

I want to let users edit a field with double data in Grails view. I want to allow Double.NaN (to void values).

There is a special char looking like a diamond with a question mark in it (in HTML) that acts like NaN, but - well - the users wont find that on their keys.

In Java it works with `Double.valueOf("NaN")`. But typing NaN in the input field will throw a IllegalArgumentException saying "NaN" is an Unparseable Number.

What method is callled for conversion? Whats the key to let it autoconvert to a double?

Comment: Please, PLEASE don't use "special values" in fields to signify non-standard events.  You almost never have to nowadays.  Stefan's answer below will work, or use a checkbox to signify "Clear this field".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `Double` instead of `double` in the domain class or command object, and use `nullable:true` in the constraints ´null´ acts as 'no data' value.

If you really want to stick to NaN, you have to register a custom propertyeditor, see http://ishanf.tumblr.com/post/434379583/custom-property-editor-for-grails.